# race condition in C# web service and timer job

Tags: c#, race-condition

The following sequence leads a race condition of sorts.

The moment a customer purchase a service, the database contains a row with a field `payment` = `false`

The customer is directed to a payment gateway. Only if the payment is successful will a web service be called. (This is a design limitation of the payment gateway)

The web service will update the status of the field `status` to `true`.

At every x interval of time I have a timer job synchronizing the status of the database row into a third party system. The third party system currently does not have the ability to update records. The job currently looks for records in the database which does not have GUID issued from the creation of the record in the third party system. It writes only those records to the third party system.

What i am experiencing is the web service sets the value of the payment to true, but the job has already written the value of payment as false.

How would I resolve this problem ?

Comment: You need a logic to check before the job updates the records

Comment: Well, can't that job write the value as true at the next update cycle?

Comment: @Oluwafemi can you please explain this lock mech, in more detail

Comment: @usr I have updated the question to address your question.

Comment: You need synchronization between the two. Do you have access to the code for both? You're going to need some kind of lock so only one is accessing the object at a time.

Comment: OK, can you only synchronize if the payment status is true?

Comment: Don't create record with `payment = false` in first place. Use another table to hold not confirmed payments. When payment is confirmed, delete record from that table and add it to one which is polled.

Comment: I have access to the code for the site, the timer job and the web serivce.

Comment: No i can write the synchronization logic, since I have the code for the timer job. So I don't have to write only on true.